# Copy and paste formated cells/range (from excel) to outlook mail

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I am using a tool (macro-enabled workbook) when sending status reports in work. But what my code does is just to copy the range as a image then paste to the body of the email as an HTML.
But the problem is that people wants to copy the contents of the range but since it is an image in the mail, they cannot do it. 
My question is, is there a way that i can add the copied cells, put it in HTML code then create an email using the html that was built?

Here are the parts of my code. The first part is to copy the range as an image then save in a location:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set intervalo = Range("B18:F21").CurrentRegion
intervalo.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, intervalo.Width, intervalo.Height)
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-100
cht.Chart.Paste
cht.Chart.Export Dir & "resp.bmp"
cht.Delete
```

Then, the body of the mail is being bulilt like this:

```
Msg = "<HTML><font face = Arial size =2>"
Msg = Msg & "Hi All, <br><br>"
Msg = Msg & "Please see below status for demand "
Msg = Msg & "<b><font color=#0033CC>"
Msg = Msg & Worksheets("Execution").Range("C8")
Msg = Msg & " - "
Msg = Msg & Worksheets("Execution").Range("C9")
Msg = Msg & "</font></b>"
Msg = Msg & ", "
Msg = Msg & "of system "
Msg = Msg & "<b><font color=#0033CC>"
Msg = Msg & Worksheets("Execution").Range("C10")
Msg = Msg & "</font></b>"
Msg = Msg & ", in environment "
Msg = Msg & "<b><font color=#0033CC>"
Msg = Msg & Worksheets("Execution").Range("C11")
Msg = Msg & "</font></b>"
Msg = Msg & ".<br>"
```

Then the image that was copied before will be inserted:

```
Msg = Msg & "<p class=section1 style='text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-ideograph;" & _
             "background:#E6E6E6'><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:Arial'>" & _
             "Contacts" & _
             "</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:Arial'><o:p></o:p></span> </p>"

Msg = Msg & "<img src='" & Dir & "resp.bmp'></img>"

Msg = Msg & "</font></b>"
```

I want to know how can I copy the actual range in the spreadhsheet "Execution" then insert it in the html code (variable Msg). 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. It is possible. You might want to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you will need to create an HTML table in our code, build its contents from the Excel cells, and set the MailItem.HTMLBody property.